# Chrome Developer Tools - Debugging, differences between Sources tab and Application tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the Developer Tools window within the Chrome Browser, there is a "Sources" tab which in the past, I have been able to set breakpoints and step through the Javascript. I am still able to do that for a web app that I wrote. However, when I try to do the same for some another web app, the javascript file does not appear on the Sources tab. Instead, I find it on the Application tab but I do not appear to have the ability to step through the breakpoints on that tab.

How does the Application tab differ from the Sources tab and how might I be able to debug the javascript file?

Comment: You're probably seeing source maps

Comment: The js files appears under "Frames/Scripts" on the Application tab. i think of source maps as mapping, say, ts code to js. I don't think that is the case here.

Comment: Can you take some screenshots?

Comment: I would have but The company policy prevents uploading of attachments. Thanks

Comment: I thought reloading the page didn't fix it, but it's working now. No idea. Looks ,like a Chrome bug